# JS pageshow event triggerring on form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the below JS to show a loading GIF while my servlet adds some data and then redirects. When I submit the form it fires the on click event no problem.  But then right after it runs the pageshow and hides the div again.  Which makes no sense to me, I'm still on the same page.  The point of the pageshow was if someone clicked back, the page doesn't get stuck on the loading GIF.  Why is the pageshow being triggered after the validation check?  What am I missing

```js
// ==== [START] Search gif hide and show ====
$("#equipSrch").click(function () {
    if ($("#search-form").valid()) {
        document.getElementById("viewSrch").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'block';
    }
});

$(window).bind('pageshow', function () {
    document.getElementById("viewSrch").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'none';
});
// ==== [END] Search gif hide and show ====
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you triggering "pageshow" somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some jquery imports, the valid() function was firing but getting an exception I missed before.  Also I failed to call the validate() function first.

```js
 // ==== [START] Search gif hide and show ====
 $("#submit").click(function() {
  $("#search-form").validate();
  if($("#search-form").valid()) {
   document.getElementById("viewSrch").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'block';
  }
 });
 
 $(window).bind('pageshow', function() {
  document.getElementById("viewSrch").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'none';
  });
 // ==== [END] Search gif hide and show ====
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```